# Creating custom analyzers using whoosh

Tags: whoosh

I am trying to implement a semantic search engine with deep NLP pipeline using Whoosh. Currently, I just have stemming analyzer, but I need to add lemmatizing and pos tagging to my analyzers.

```
 schema = Schema(id=ID(stored=True, unique=True), stem_text=TEXT(stored= True, analyzer=StemmingAnalyzer()))
```

I want to know how to add custom analyzers to my schema.

Comment: I am using Whoosh 2.7.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a custom lemmatization filter and integrate into an existing whoosh analyzer. Quoting from [Whoosh docs](https://whoosh.readthedocs.io/en/latest/stemming.html#lemmatization):

> Whoosh does not include any lemmatization functions, but if you have
>   separate lemmatizing code you could write a custom
>   `whoosh.analysis.Filter` to integrate it into a Whoosh analyzer.

You can create an analyzer by combining a tokenizer with filters:

```
my_analyzer = RegexTokenizer() | LowercaseFilter() | StopFilter() | LemmatizationFilter()
```

or by adding a filter to an existing analyzer:

```
my_analyzer = StandardAnalyzer() | LemmatizationFilter()
```

You can define a filter like:

```
def LemmatizationFilter(self, stream):
    for token in stream:
        yield token
```

Comment: This is the analyser I am using now.                                            `my_analyzer = RegexTokenizer()| StopFilter()| LowercaseFilter() | StemFilter()  | Lemmatizer() `  In this analyser will the lemmatizer overrides stem filter or both stemming and lemmatizing is applied to my indexing